# Xpath query is returning NULL

Tags: php, html, xpath

I am trying to maintain some PHP code which is doing web page scraping.  The web page has changed so an update is needed, but I'm not so experienced with Xpath so am struggling.

Basically this is the section of html that is relevant

```
<div class="carousel-item-wrapper">
    <picture class="">
        <source srcset="/medias/tea-tree-skin-clearing-foaming-cleanser-1-640x640.jpg?context=product-images/h3b/hd3/8796813918238/tea-tree-skin-clearing-foaming-cleanser_1-640x640.jpg" media="(min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 1024)">
        <source srcset="/medias/tea-tree-skin-clearing-foaming-cleanser-1-320x320.jpg?context=product-images/h09/h9a/8796814049310/tea-tree-skin-clearing-foaming-cleanser_1-320x320.jpg" media="(max-width: 640px)">
        <img srcset="/medias/myimage.jpg" alt="150 ML" class="">
    </picture>
</div>
```

I am trying to extract the srcset attribute from the IMG tag which is the value of "/medias/myimage.jpg".  I'm using XPATH Helper chrome plugin to help me and I have the following xpath;

```
//div[@class="carousel-item-wrapper"]/picture/img/@srcset
```

In the plugin, it returns exact what I expect, so it appears to work fine.

If I also use an online xpath tester http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php then it also works OK.

But in my PHP code I get a null value.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->strictErrorChecking = false;
    $dom->recover = true;

    @$dom->loadHtml($html);
    $xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);        

   //Other xPath queries executed OK.

    $node = $xPath->query('//div[@class="carousel-item-wrapper"]/picture/img/@srcset')->item(0);

    if ($node === NULL)
        writelog("Node is NULL");   // <-- Writes NULL to the log file!
```

I have of course tried a lot of different variations on this, trying not to specify the attribute name etc.  But all with not luck.

What am I doing wrong?  I'm sure it must be something simple, but I can't spot it.

Other extracts using my PHP code on the same HTML document are working OK.  So it is just this element causing me trouble.

Comment: Which PHP class are you using to read/edit/query your HTML data?

Comment: Could you add some details how are you instantiating the $xPath etc.?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, remove the "@" before "loadHtml", you will see the error "Tag source invalid in Entity". If you can edit the html, you should add self-closing tags for the source tag

Comment: `@$dom->loadHtml($html);` < remove the `@` that suppresses errors so you'll not know if that's failed - which it might since your HTML isn't valid.

Comment: @christophe ninja'd :P

Comment: PHP DOM isn't very good with HTML, you have to use an XHTML variant or follow the [HTML5 Polyglot markup](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-polyglot/) which allows you to still use HTML5 but using a well-defined structure better supported by XML parsers.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I will look to improve the code as suggested.  The answer from jhmckimm worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's DOMXPath class seems to have trouble with self-closing tags. You need to add a double forward-slash if you're looking to find a self-closing tag, so your new xPath query should be:

`//div[@class="carousel-item-wrapper"]/picture//img/@srcset`

Comment: That worked.  Thanks a lot, I never would have found that!

Comment: For the benefit of anyone else coming here: XPath handles self-closing tags just fine. What is described here appears to be a workaround for a bug in the particular XPath processor being used.